# Spring MVC CrudRepository findByIn

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, repository, crud

I have a CrudRepository that is supposed to make a query with an array (`findByIn`). In my repository tests it works, but when I try to use the query in my service, it doesn't work. Could someone explain why it doesn't work? Here is my setup (excluding some code irrelevant to the question)

Database model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Place")
public class Place implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "placeId", nullable = false)
    private Long placeId;

    @Column(name = "owner", nullable = false)
    private String owner;

    public Long getPlaceId() {
    return placeId;
    }

    public void setPlaceId(Long placeId) {
        this.placeId = placeId;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PlaceRepository extends CrudRepository<Place, Long> {
    List<Place> findByPlaceIdIn(Long[] placeId);
}
```

Service (this is the part not working):

```
@Service
public class PlaceService {

    @Autowired
    private PlaceRepository placeRepository;

    public List<Place> getPlaces(Long[] placeIds) {
        return placeRepository.findByPlaceIdIn(placeIds);
    }
}
```

The problem is that in my service `placeRepository.findByPlaceIdIn(placeIds)` returns 0 objects if `placeIds` contains more than one item. If `placeIds` contains just one item, the query works fine. I tried replacing `return placeRepository.findByPlaceIdIn(placeIds)` with this piece of code that does the query for every array item one by one (this actually works, but I'd like to get the query work as it should):

```
    ArrayList<Place> places = new ArrayList<Place>();
    for (Long placeId : placeIds) {
        Long[] id = {placeId};
        places.addAll(placeRepository.findByPlaceIdIn(id));
    }
    return places;
```

I know that the repository should work, because I have a working test for it:

```
public class PlaceRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private PlaceRepository repository;

    private static Place place;
    private static Place place2;
    private static Place otherUsersPlace;

    @Test
    public void testPlacesfindByPlaceIdIn() {
        place = new Place();
        place.setOwner(USER_ID);

        place2 = new Place();
        place2.setOwner(USER_ID);

        place = repository.save(place);
        place2 = repository.save(place2);
        Long[] ids = {place.getPlaceId(), place2.getPlaceId()};
        assertEquals(repository.findByPlaceIdIn(ids).size(), 2);
    }
}
```

I also have another repository for other model, which also uses `findByIn` and it works fine. I can't see any relevant difference between the repositories. I thought it might offer some more details to show the working repository, so I included it below:

Database model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="LocalDatabaseRow")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=false)
public class LocalDatabaseRow implements Serializable {
    public LocalDatabaseRow() {}

    public LocalDatabaseRow(RowType rowType) {
        this.rowType = rowType;
    }

    public enum RowType {
        TYPE1,
        TYPE2
    };

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("rowType")
    @Column(name = "rowType")
    private RowType rowType;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public RowType getRowType() {
        return rowType;
    }
    public void setRowType(RowType rowType) {
        this.rowType = rowType;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface LocalDatabaseRowRepository extends CrudRepository<LocalDatabaseRow, Long> {
    List<LocalDatabaseRow> findByRowTypeAndUserIdIn(RowType type, String[] userId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a list instead :

findByPlaceIdIn(List placeIdList);

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I already tried using list, and it didn't work any better.

Comment: I don't use CRUD that much, you can user JpaSpecificationExecutor, it will work fine.

Comment: If I can't find a good solution I might consider using something else than CRUD, but for now I would like to solve the problem, not get around it. In my original post I already presented a way to get around the problem by making the queries one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code (the repository declaration in the service):

```
@Autowired
private placeRepository placeRepository;
```

Should be:

```
@Autowired
private PlaceRepository placeRepository;
```

Comment: That typo happened when I excluded irrelevant code, so the typo isn't in my real code. Hence, this is not the issue. But thanks for checking the code so thoroughly anyway :) I corrected the typo from my question.

Comment: It is true, I stopped reading when sawing the typo. The code seems fine. Maybe a second look at the repository implementation would help. Debugging should also give a better hint... I do not have other ideas